# Updating map polygons and map legend with selected color option from dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, dictionary, d3.js, colorbrewer

I am a rookie programmer trying to make an interactive map with d3.  So far, I have been able to update the colors of the polygons in the SVG choropleth (quantile) map by selecting a Colorbrewer CSS color scheme from a dropdown menu.

```
d3.select("select#ColorSelection")
    .on("keyup", function() {d3.selectAll("svg#Mapsvg").attr("class", this.value)})
    .on("change", function() {d3.selectAll("svg#Mapsvg").attr("class", this.value)});
```

However, the color boxes for the map legend are stuck on the blue color scheme, no matter what other color scheme option is chosen in the dropdown menu.  Here is an [example](http://i1299.photobucket.com/albums/ag70/geomapper123/MapLegendColorNotUpdating_zps3903674a.png).  I have tried some things, such as adding additional code that simply copies the code above, but replaces "svg#Mapsvg" with the map legend "svg#Legendsvg", but have not had any luck.

How can I update the map legend ("svg#Legendsvg") and the map itself with the same color scheme selected from the dropdown menu?

Apologies ahead of time if I am missing something very basic.  Thanks for any help you can offer!

Here is the code for the map legend color boxes, for reference:

```
var legends = d3.select('svg#Legendsvg')
var legendbars = legends.selectAll('rect')
        .data(legend)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 5)
        .attr('y', function(d, i) {return (i*30)+25})
        .attr('height',28)
        .attr('width',30)
        .attr('class', function (d) {return quants(d)} )
        ;
```

And reference code for the dropdown menu:

```
    <p>Color Scheme: 
        <select id="ColorSelection">
        <option value="Blues" selected>Blues</option>
        <option value="Greys">Greys</option>
        <option value="Greens">Greens</option>
        <option value="Oranges">Oranges</option>
        <option value="Reds">Reds</option>
        <option value="Purples">Purples</option>
        <option value="YlGn">Yellow-Green</option>
        <option value="YlGnBu">Yellow-Green-Blue</option>
        <option value="GnBu">Green-Blue</option>
        <option value="BuGn">Blue-Green</option>
        <option value="PuBuGn">Purple-Blue-Green</option>
        <option value="PuBu">Purple-Blue</option>
        <option value="BuPu">Blue-Purple</option>
        <option value="RdPu">Red-Purple</option>
        <option value="PuRd">Purple-Red</option>
        <option value="OrRd">Orange-Red</option>
        <option value="YlOrRd">Yellow-Orange-Red</option>
        <option value="YlOrBr">Yellow-Orange-Brown</option>
        </select></br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear that you have actually given your legend bars an id value of `Legendsvg`.  So if you try selecting using #Legendsvg d3 will not get the elements you are trying to select.  Try adding

```
.attr(id, "Legendsvg")
```

to your legend creation statements and then edit your keyup / change functions to:

```
{d3.selectAll("svg#Mapsvg, svg#Legendsvg")...
```